# Calculating shabbat candle lighting time

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting, zemanim

Is it possible to calculate the candle lighting time based on location and date alone?

Assume all you have is a GPS, a watch and a calculator.

Comment: Mordechai Ben Daniel, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Keep in mind that one is not allowed to start Shabos at a later time than the community's latest starting time. So if you "prove" that candle lighting should be 3 minutes later than the time that the community lights, you still can not start Shabos later than when the community does if you proof is not accepted. But if you are on the road or stuck in an airport outside of a city, start calculating - You may even want to use Rabeinu Tam time :-)

Comment: Also can Be done With myzmanim.com

Comment: Although that's going to be at the end of kabbolas shabbos/borchu which is usually after that time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Theoretically yes (assuming candle lighting is just 18 minutes less than sunset), as [here's the formula for sunset time based on date, latitude, and longitude](http://www.moonstick.com/sunriseset.htm); but it's a doozy!

Comment: Interesting that no one adjusts the 18 minutes.

Comment: what about altitude?

Comment: @YDK - adjust it for what? IIUC, the 18 minutes are a sort of buffer zone to ensure that Shabbos won't be violated. That doesn't change depending on where a person is located.

Comment: @Sam - Unless you're way above sea level, like in an airplane, altitude won't have a significant effect on the time of sunset. A more complicated question is how to deal with mountainous terrain; see this link for a comprehensive discussion about it: http://www.chaitables.com/chaiintro.html

Comment: @Dave, we treat the 18 as buffer zone, but those into chumra-of-the-month club would point to the Yereim, who holds halachic sunset is 18 minutes before what we call sunset.  Was his opinion 18 absolute minutes or relative minutes? I don't know the material well enough (but it's based on the whole discussion of how many miles the average person walks between sunrise, sunset, dusk, etc.)

Comment: @Shalom - interesting, but somehow I doubt that's what YDK meant. ;)

Comment: That's what I meant.  The opinions on 3/4 of a mil (how much and when) are representations of a qualitative aspect- how does the sky look during the period of doubt.  This should change with the latitude.  I was thinking that Rav Moshe, for example, prorates the time in between 1st shkiah and Rabeinu Tam's tzais because those have known reference points (sunset and "as dark as it was in Europe at 72 minutes), whereas he may not have known what qualities the Yereim required.  If that's true, though, why does Rav Moshe prorate the Geonim's bein hashemashos- it should not be dependant on R"T's?

Comment: @YDK - so you were just assuming that the 18-minute shiur is due to the Yereim?

Comment: I never knew there was another reason for exactly 18 minutes.  The Biur Halacha writes that tosefes shabbos, which is an halacha, is certainly less than than 3/4 of a mil and suggests close to a 1/2 hour before  (R"T's) tzais.  That would be less than 18 minutes.  Rav Moshe brings 18 minutes before shkiah for the yereim using the 24 minute mil.  He then says some light a 1/2 hour before shkiah, some 1/4 of an hour which is appropriate because then you get the yereim and tosefes (I don't know if he means concurrently or 18 + 2).  I guess that's the source for the 20 minute b/f shkiah calendar.

Comment: @Dave , sunset in the Washington Heights is considerably later than in the Lower East End of Manhattan in the summer time. The full sun can still be seen in the Heights when the official time for sunset has occured for the Lower East End. 
(I asked a couple of poseks about that and was told to pretend I didn't ask)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the common custom is indeed calculated based on latitude and longitude alone. However, this is certainly not a unanimous assumption, considering that in addition to latitude and longitude, your own elevation, as well as the elevation of the western horizon, will affect the appearance of sunset. I believe Yeshivat Birkat Moshe, in Maale Adumim, under the auspices of Rav Nachum Rabinovitch, *shelita"h*, accepts Shabbat well before the sea-level calculations of the popular sunset tables.

See [Shabbath 118b](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.55?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all):

> א"ר יוסי יהא חלקי ממכניסי שבת בטבריא וממוציאי שבת בצפורי
>
> Said Rabbi Yosi: Let my lot be of those who enter the Sabbath in Tiberia (lower elevation = earlier time; see Rashi *ad loc*) and of those who leave Sabbath in Zippori (higher elevation = later time).

See also [here](http://www.myzmanim.com/elevation.aspx?vars=US10977/////////////////499024) and [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/shana/rabinovits-2.htm), as well as *Shu"t Siach Nachum* Responsum 17, p. 40.